# Centers of Figures inscribed in a circle

Tags: geometry

I have a question regarding shapes that are inscribed in a circle. If a regular polygon is inscribed in a circle, is it true that the center of it would be the center of the circle in which it is inscribed?

Now, what if it was not a regular polygon but a shape with to axis of symmetry, like a rectangle. If that was inscribed in a circle, would the center of the circle be the center of the rectangle also (where the diagonals intersect)? Would this apply to any equiangular figure, even if its sides are not the same length?

Then, if we take a polygon with side lengths that are equal like a rhombus but doesn't have equal angle measures, will the centers be the same?

Lastly, would the centers be the same if it is a figure that is not equiangular or with equivalent side lengths like a parallelogram (which is not a rectangle or a rhombus), or an isosceles trapezoid? And if the center of an isosceles trapezoid will not, will the intersection point of its two diagonals?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I don't see how a rhombus / parallelogram  can be inscribed in a circle

Comment: Sorry my good sir, in my confusion I forgot about that. Yes please disregard that part about the parallelogram and rhombus.

Comment: If it has all same-length sides, it needs same angles to be inscribed in circle...

Comment: In your neither-nor case: it is possible to inscribe a trapezoid in a half-circle, so center and crossing of diagonals will not be on circlecenter.

Comment: Your question is interesting, but incomplete. You have to provide the definition you are using for the center of a polygon.  Note that for an inscribed polygon, equilateral implies equiangular.

Comment: Draw a line from any point on the circle to any other. The bisector of this line will also bisect the circle. Any bisector of a circle will go through the center of this circle.